# Proving that $(v_1 - v_2, v_2 - v_3, \dots, v_{n - 1} - v_n, v_n)$ spans $V$ if $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ spans $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone know how to prove the following without using determinants? Our class uses Axler's textbook, which presents linear algebra without determinants.

*Prove that if $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ spans $V$, then so does $(v_1 - v_2, v_2 - v_3, \dots, v_{n - 1} - v_n, v_n)$, which is obtained by subtracting from each vector (except the last one) the following vector.*

Clearly, you could show that $\det(A) \neq 0$ where the columns of $A$ are the respective vectors in the second spanning set, but I'm looking for another way.

Comment: You're wrong in your last sentence. The matrix you're talking about doesn't even need to be a square matrix.

Answer (score 6):

You need to show that each of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ can be obtained as linear combinations of $v_1-v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}-v_n,v_n$.

We have
$$
v_n=v_n,\ v_{n-1}=(v_{n-1}-v_n)+v_n,\ \ldots,v_2=(v_2-v_3)+v_2,\ v_1=(v_1-v_2)+v_2.
$$